# Check license using awk and regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl, shell, awk

I submit jobs to my university's SGE batch engine and am running a program called COMSOL, which has a limited number of licenses than can be run at a given time. When I submit a job, it sits in a queue for a while until it's my turn. If all of the COMSOL licenses are being used, my job immediately quits and I have to resubmit it, potentially waiting several days before it tries again. I'd like to avoid that. I've created an alias (`comsollicense`) to a program that outputs all of the licensing of COMSOL and its different modules. Among them is a line that looks like this:

```
Users of COMSOL:  (Total of 7 licenses issued;  Total of 7 licenses in use)
```

There are other lines in the output that look similar:

```
Users of WAVEOPTICS:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 0 licenses in use)
Users of CHEM:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 2 licenses in use)
etc....
```

In my SGE job script, I want to select the line that starts with "Users of COMSOL" and compare the number of licenses in use to the number issued. If they're the same number, I want it to wait, check again later, and when there is an available license, I want my COMSOL to run. I was thinking something like:

```
awk '{
    comsollicense
    SOME CODE HERE TO EXTRACT numIssued AND numUsed
    while (numIssued == numUsed){
        sleep 300
        comsollicense
        CODE TO EXTRACT numIssued AND numUSED
    }
}'
comsol -inputfile test.mph
```

Is this an appropriate approach? I was thinking I could use a regular expression in there, but I am not really familiar with how to program regular expressions. How can I extract the number of licenses issued and the number in use?

Comment: Wouldn't it be kind of rude to have your job sitting in the queue not doing anything while other people are waiting? While your job is sleeping, other jobs could be running that use licenses that *are* available.

Comment: No, you are trying to use awk as shell. Write a shell script to call cosmolicense and awk and sleep.

Comment: Usually the licenses free up relatively quickly, so this job isn't going to be sitting there for hours, maybe 30 minutes or so. Comparing 30 minutes, to days of waiting for it to try again, seems OK to me. Ideally there would be some feature integrated into SGE that could check the license before starting my job, but that doesn't seem to be an option.

Any ideas of what my regular expression would look like if I wrote a shell script? I had tried something like `/'Users of COMSOL:  \(Total of (\d) licenses issued;  Total of (\d) licenses in use\)'/` but that didn't match anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prints the number of issued licenses:

```
awk '/COMSOL/ { print $6; }'  comsollicense
```

Prints the number of licenses in use:

```
awk '/COMSOL/ { print $11; }'  comsollicense
```

You may use this in a shell-script. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! That's a lot more complicated than I would have expected it to be. I think I need to look more into learning regular expressions.

Comment: You don't need much regex using awk.  Using the field positions `awk '/Users of COMSOL/ { print $6 - $11 }' comsollicense` would work for getting the difference as a single output.